# Cannot innitialise superclass from Ray actor process

Tags: python, numpy, ray

I am trying to parallelise a sampling process, so I created a Sampler object. The Sampler depends on two datasets, which are large (stored as numpy arrays), which are arguments to the constructor. To avoid having duplicates in the object store, my idea has been to first use ray.put to add the object to the object store and then initialise the Sampler objects with the corresponding ids.

Moreover, I don't want to add the decorators to the Sampler class. Instead, I created a subclass of Sampler, `RemoteSampler` which decorates the methods of the `superclass` and modifies them by adding the `.remote()` call. However, I seem to be unable to initialise the `superclass` from the `ActorClass`. I get a type error:

> TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not ActorClass(RemoteSampler).

Skeleton code below:

```
import ray
import numpy as np

class Sampler(object):

    def __init__(self, train_data, d_train_data, *others):

        # these can be big, so we want to have only one copy that
        # mutliple actors share
        if isinstance(train_data, np.ndarray):
            self.train_data = train_data
        else:
            self.train_data = ray.get(train_data)

        if isinstance(d_train_data, np.ndarray):
            self.d_train_data = d_train_data
        else:
            self.d_train_data = ray.get(d_train_data)

        # Initialise the rest of the sampler state
        self.d1 = {}
        self.d2 = {}

    def __call__(self, features, n_samples):

        a, b, c = self._sampling_loop(features, n_samples)

        # process a, b, c and return something

        return a, b, c, features

    def build_lookups(self, X):
        self.d1 = {0: X[0]}
        self.d2 = {1: X[1]}
        return self.d1, self.d2

    def _sampling_loop(self, features, n_samples):
        # Use train_data, d_train data and other attributes return some data to call
        return 0, 0, 0

@ray.remote
class RemoteSampler(Sampler):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(RemoteSampler, self).__init__(*args)
        self.__call__ = ray.method(self.__call__, num_return_vals=4)
        self.build_lookups = ray.method(self.build_lookups, num_return_vals=2)

    def __call__(self, anchor, num_samples):
        return self.__call__(anchor, num_samples).remote()

    def build_lookups(self, X):
        a, b, c = self.build_lookups.remote(X)
        return a, b, c


def _fit_parallel(*args):
    # method of a class where the RemoteSampler objects are initialised
    # copy large objects to object store
    train_data, d_train_data, *others = args
    train_data_id = ray.put(train_data)
    d_train_data_id = ray.put(d_train_data)
    n_args = (train_data_id, d_train_data_id, *others)
    return [RemoteSampler.remote(*n_args) for _ in range(4)]
```